# Alerts for SharePoint document library changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-alerts

Looking for best practice for sending alerts to the members of the SharePoint site collection when an item is modified in a document library.

Answer (score 0):

Get alerts on all changes in a document library in SharePoint

Here are steps:

1.Go to the list or library and make sure no items are selected.

2.From the list of options for the list or library, select the ... (ellipses), and then select Alert Me.

3.In the Alert me when items change dialog, change or fill in the options you want.
[image]

4.Select OK.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: They want to notify the team something happened on the site or document library how to notify his team.